# How can I select subset of attributes from an Nosql database with a condition using spring data repository?

Tags: java, spring, attributes, nosql, repository

In a NoSQL DB(DynamoDB), the table has 10 attributes. I only need to get 3 attributes from it. Two of them are the composite primary key(id, name), the rest one is isCreated. If I want to select all the items which isCreated is true, how can I define the name of the method in the repository of spring data? which annotation should I use？
In the relational database, the SQL would be like this:
"select id, name from table_name where isCreated=true". 
1. In this way, I can get two attributes，but it can't get rid of the items whose isCreated is false.

```
@Query(string = "id, name")
public findByIdAndName(String id, String name);
```

2. This way will throw an exception. it said, "can't scan table or using @EnableScan to enable it".

```
@Query(string = "id, name")
public findByIdAndNameAndIsCreated(String id, String name, boolean isCreated);
```

3. This way can get rid of the items whose isCreated is false. but it selected all the ten attributes. But I only need two.

   @Query(string = "id, name")
   @EnableScan
   public findByIdAndNameAndIsCreated(String id, String name, boolean isCreated);

What is the correct answer?

Comment: I think projections can help you https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Comment: Thanks, Seti. That's really helpful.

Comment: finally, I use Dynamodb API called query() + Dynamodb projections API solved the problem. This is the easiest way for it. Thanks.